# Page sizes inside PDF are wrong when putting images as separate pages

Tags: imagick

I'm using Image Magic 7.1

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-40 beta Q16-HDRI x86_64 21a5642bc:20220620 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): fontconfig freetype jng jpeg pangocairo png x zlib
Compiler: gcc (10.2)
```

When i attempt to place two image files into a PDF a very strange thing happens: Image sizes are correct, but page sizes of the resulting PDF are wrong, and the images are stretched to fit the page (However, if you were to extract those images, you'd see that the sizes are identical).

I am trying to do so in two different ways:

```
convert file.jpeg -resize 1795x1287^ -gravity center -extent 1795x1287 /tmp/1.jpeg
convert back.png /tmp/2.jpeg
convert /tmp/1.jpeg /tmp/2.jpeg output-test.pdf
```

`back.png` is already in the correct resoluion. I can see that temporary files are of correct resolution, but the PDF is wrong.

I am also trying to do this in a single command:

```
convert \
    file.jpeg -resize 1795x1287^ -gravity center -extent 1795x1287 \
    back.png \
    -quality 100 \
    output.pdf
```

The resulting file is displayed thusly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to generate the file the way i wanted, but i had to abandon using Image Magic for the last step. I have tried `-density` and `-page`, but to no avail. What worked in the end:

```
convert file.jpeg -resize 1795x1287^ -gravity center -extent 1795x1287 -density 300 -quality 100 /tmp/1.jpeg
convert back.png -density 300 -quality 100 /tmp/2.jpeg
img2pdf /tmp/1.jpeg /tmp/2.jpeg --pagesize 1795x1287 -o output-test.pdf
```